# 2 Divs Overlap each other using JQuery Mobile in HTML5

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am designing a page by using Jquery Mobile and HTML5 and i am facing the problem when i try to put 2 divs in one div for my requirements.
It works fine for Desktop Browsers but when i see result in Mobile Browser the divs overlap each other.
I am stuck with this issue from last 2 hours and need a bit hint ot solution of my problem :)

Here is [link](http://mobiletest.me/#d=Samsung_Galaxy_Y_portrait&u=http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/Smash.aspx) to see what i am facing :(
Here is [link](http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/Smash.aspx) of desktop browser in which every thing is fine :)

Here is my HTML 5 Code.

```
 <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>
            <img src="images/smashlogo.jpg" />
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-dividertheme="b">
            <li>
                <img src="images/H.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px; width:90%">
                    <a style=" font-size:10px; color: Black;">Great Deal- Collect 10 nights and get 1 free at Hotels.com</a><div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/H1.jpg" />
                </div></div>

                <%--<div style="margin-left:11px; margin-top:11px;">Great  <img src="images/expedia.png" /></div>--%>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Expedia.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px; color: Black;">Earn Rewards with Expedia Hotels & Flights!</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Expedia1.jpg" /></div>
                <%--<select name="subject" id="subject" data-placeholder="true" data-native-menu="false">


                    <option value="Art">Art</option>
                    <option value="Band">Band</option>
                    <option value="Choir">Choir</option>
                    <option value="Design">Design</option>
                    <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
                </select>--%>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Vegas.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">myVEGAS Slots</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Vegas1.jpg" /></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Castle.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Castle Clash by IGG</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Castle1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/W.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Download the free Walgreens app</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/W1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Expedia.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Earn Rewards with Expedia Hotels & Flights!</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Expedia1.jpg" /></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Vegas.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">myVEGAS Slots</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Vegas1.jpg" /></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Castle.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Castle Clash by IGG</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Castle1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/W.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Download the free Walgreens app</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/W1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Expedia.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Earn Rewards with Expedia Hotels & Flights!</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Expedia1.jpg" /></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Vegas.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">myVEGAS Slots</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Vegas1.jpg" /></div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/Castle.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-left: 3px; margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Castle Clash by IGG</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/Castle1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/W.jpg" />
                <div style="margin-top: 11px;">
                    <a style="font-size:10px;color: Black;">Download the free Walgreens app</a></div>
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <img src="images/W1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <%--<li><a href="option3.html">Option 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="option4.html">Option 4</a></li>--%>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>
            &copy; 2012 Smashing Magazine</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem only happens when your screen is very narrow it works well on the iphone:
[here](http://mobiletest.me/#d=iPhone_5_portrait&u=http://webcalendar.pcprosinc.com/Smash.aspx).

I tried the desktop website in the minimum screen size your site works fine with is 305px screen width.
Add the following css to tweak the code for smaller screens:

```
@media (max-width: 305px){
    //add style here
}
```

or you can make a min width for the entire page because there aren't many screens with that size:

```
html,body{
    min-width:305px;
}
```